# Adding key and value to a dictionary within a function in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm currently trying to add a new key and value to an empty dictionary by using a function with three variables.

The following is what I have, but it doesn't work...

```
def add_fruit(inventory, fruit, quantity=0):
    new_inventory = {}
    for key in inventory: 
        new_inventory[fruit] = quantity
    return new_inventory
```

What do I have to add or change to make this function work properly? 
For example, if I want to add 10 strawberries I'd say `new_inventory["strawberries"] = 10` but in the function I fail to add this to the dictionary.

I would appreciate some help or suggestions!

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Is the indentation correct? `return` should be inside the function. 2. What do you mean by "fail to add this to the dictionary"? How do you know? How and where did you check that?

Comment: Is it actually necessary to create a new dictionary to add a key-value pair?

Comment: @DeepSpace I corrected the return to be inside of the function. I tried to print(add_fruit(new_dictionary, "strawberries", 10) but the function only returns {}.

Comment: @DominiqueM Well, if you pass in an empty dictionary as the `inventory` argument then the `for` loop will never execute, thus an empty dictionary will be returned.

Comment: Can you share an example with the desired output? You actually only add `fruit` to the dictionary with the value of `quantity`, can you explain what is the for loop being used for ?

Comment: @EvyatarMeged I would like to see {'strawberries' : 10} as output for example. I used the loop to see if I could make it work, but so far not unfortunately

Comment: @DominiqueM okay, than you pass `strawberries` as the `fruit` parameter and `10` to `quantity`. What is `inventory` being used for? why the loop?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a `list` of `fruit` and `quantity` ? And I'm equally interested in the point @EvyatarMeged is getting to

Comment: Can we just have your starting variables and expected output, if it is just `strawberry` and `10`  this is no need for this loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you are adding a new key multiple times (`for key in inventory`) and don't add other keys from the original dictionary?

I'd suggest you unpack the original dictionary and add a new key like this:

```
def add_fruit(inventory, fruit, quantity=0):
    return {**inventory, fruit: quantity}
```

More on python unpacking: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems to solve my problem (the **inventory part)! Now I should figure out what ** exactly means :)

Comment: @DominiqueM I've added a PEP link to my answer!

Answer (score 1):

> This is how I solved it.

```
def add_fruit(inventory, fruit, quantity=0):
    inventory[fruit] = quantity
    return inventory
def add_to_fruit(inventory, add_more):
    for key,value in inventory.items():
        if len(inventory) == 1:
            inventory[key] += add_more
        return inventory
            
# make these tests work...
new_inventory = {}
add_fruit(new_inventory, 'strawberries', 10)
#  test that 'strawberries' in new_inventory
print('strawberries' in new_inventory)
#  test that new_inventory['strawberries'] is 10
print(new_inventory)
add_to_fruit(new_inventory, 25)
#  test that new_inventory['strawberries'] is now 35)
print(new_inventory)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can update your dictionary via function:

#### `dict.__setitem__`

Simply set an item via `setitem` or its syntactic sugar `[]`:

```
def add_fruit(inventory, fruit, quantity=0):
    inventory[fruit] = quantity
    return inventory
```

#### `dict.update`

Create a dictionary and update your existing dictionary with this one:

```
def add_fruit(inventory, fruit, quantity=0):
    inventory[fruit] = quantity
    return inventory
```

#### Create new dictionary

Unpack the existing dictionary while adding a new item, [as described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52466458/9209546) by @ArtyonNeustroev.